# bi-gram probability

Tags: python, nlp, artificial-intelligence, probability, n-gram

Trying to find the probability of a phrase using bi-gram

`filename.txt`

```
# how many times bigram occurs
bg_count = bigrams.count(('word1', 'word2'))

# probabilty of bigram in text P(word1 word2)
bg_count/number_of_bigrams
```

Comment: Is your goal to get probability of "life might" given the first word is "life", or just probability of the bigram?

Comment: My goal is to just find the probability of the phrase ‘life might’.

Comment: @NabilaEusha can you share `filename.txt` ?

Comment: Then it should be `bg_count/number_of_bigrams` instead of `bg_count/some_count`

Comment: @NabilaEusha Also note that for really small numbers (like probabilities) it's worth operating log values to avoid loss of precision

Comment: @NabilaEusha what's your definition of correct?

Comment: I found my error. its all good now :) @Marat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a bigram langauge model:

`P(w1,w2,w3,...wn) = P(w1)*P(w2|w1)*P(w3|w2).....*P(wn-1|wn)`

So `P(life, might) = P(life)*P(might|life)` where

- `P(life) = Count(life)/Number of unigrams`
- `P(might|life) = Count(life, might)/Count(life)`

**Code to calculate `P(life might)` using bigram model:**

```
p_life = s.count("life")/len(s)
p_might_given_life = bigrams.count(('life', 'might'))/s.count('life')
p_life_might = p_life * p_might_given_life
print (p_life_might)
```

Output:

```
0.0024752475247524753
```

**Log probabilities**

Since probabilities <=1 and it is not safe to multiply many small numbers, we usually use the log probabilities since it converts multiplication to additions. And since the log is a monotone increasing function, the comparison between different log probabilities will be the same as comparing the actual probabilities.

`log(p_life_might) = log(p_life * p_might_given_life)`

`= log(p_life) + log(p_might_given_life)`

Code:

```
print (math.log(p_life)+math.log(p_might_given_life))
```

output:

```
-6.0014148779611505
```

Comment: @NabilaEusha I showed the concept behind calculation of the bigram probability. I cannot code the answer for you.